# Circular saw blade clogs nonuniformly

Tags: circular-saw

I rip cut few pine boards today with my circular saw and noticed that only a third part of a blade is clogged up. Should I be worried about unbalanced blade or some arbor problems?

[image: Back]

[image: Front]

Comment: If the blade is off center then the teeth on one side are doing all the cutting. The blade could be off center if it does not fit snugly on the arbor.

Answer (score 1):

You should only be worried about it if it's a problem with respect to your woodworking. Circular saws are by their nature not extremely precise tools. There's a lot of potential for movement as you work.

Reasons for your findings could be a warped blade, a bent arbor, worn motor bearings, sloppy blade installation, or a number of other things.